# How to set global header in Laravel TestCase?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I am using build-in Laravel TestCase for testing my REST API.
Each endpoint requires `Accept:application/json` header.

How can I set this header globally for each response in `TestCase`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`json`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#testing-json-apis) method. It sets automatically the headers for you and you can use it like this.

```
$this->json('GET', 'my-end-point');
```